# Replacement algorithms

Tags: java, algorithm

```
for(k = i - 1; k >= 0; k--) {
    if(frame[j] == page[k])
        break;
    least = least < k ? least : k;        
}
```

I don't understand this line " `least = least < k ? least : k;` "

can any one explain it for me

Comment: It's a ternary operator: `condition ? ifTrue : ifFalse`.

Comment: Please read the Java info on conditional operators here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html

Answer (score 6):

It's equivalent to

```
least = Math.min(least, k);
```

or

```
if (!(least < k)) {
    least = k
}
```

See also: [the Java documentation on the ternary operator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/op2.html) (scroll to the "The Conditional Operators" section).

Comment: I'm going to be unbelievably pedantic and point out that `least = least < k ? least : k;` is not quite equivalent to `if (!(least < k)) { least = k; }`. If `least` has type `Integer` then the code `Integer a = Integer.MIN_VALUE, least = a; int k = 0; least = least < k ? least : k; System.out.println(least == a);` produces `false`, where as if you use the `if` version it produces `true`.

Answer (score 1):

```
least = least < k ? least : k;
```

It's equivalent to,

```
if(least < k)
    least = least;
else
    least = k;
```